# Cor.test not working Error in density.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, correlation

I am new to R and have been trying to run a correlation test between distance from the river and the density. I have pasted what I can do below. 
However I think it thinks my data isn't numeric... What should I do//what am I doing wrong? 
Let me know, 
Thanks :)

`View(Rivers)`
`attach(Rivers)`

`The following objects are masked from Near_Rivers:
Density, Distance From the river`

`head(Rivers)
A tibble: 6 x 2`

```
`Distance From the river` Density
   <chr>                       <dbl>
1 0-0.5                          70
2 0.5-1                          58
3 1-1.5                          52
4 1.5-2                          28
5 2-2.5                          15
6 2.5-3                          10



cor(Distance From the river, density())
Error in density.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: It seems as if the variable is called `Density` but you are using the function `density()` as argument to `cor()`. A simple typo?